# Sending mass email with AWS lambda, ses, sqs, sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'll be needing to send out approximately 200-300k emails a week for our weekly newsletter. This number is expected to increase over time which is why I thought of letting lambda handle the scaling for us.

There will be a UI for employees to trigger the sending of these emails. My initial thought was to add the list of email addresses to a SNS topic and have the lambda function subscribed to it to trigger the actual sending of the emails. I've read that this may lead to some unexpected behavior and isn't the best for tracking down bugs.

Our current limit is 90 emails per second. This combined with the max time to execute a lambda function being 5 minutes makes me wonder how to split this up. Do I need to batch send these to SNS so multiple lambda containers can be spun up evenly to do the work? I understand that lambda can scale up for events like adding files to S3 but how would I explicitly tell lambda to spin up multiple to handle all the emails that need to be sent? Is there a better design pattern for this?

My other thought was to add the emails into an SQS queue so the emails can be persisted incase of errors but would need to do some workaround to make that play nicely with lambda.

## Update

I'm a few years late, but Lambda worked like a charm. Here is blog post detailing the architecture: https://read.iopipe.com/how-to-use-aws-lambda-to-send-high-volume-emails-at-scale-10efe65b2f32

And a follow up post on more specifics and lessons learned: https://read.iopipe.com/6-lessons-learned-sending-mass-emails-with-aws-lambda-3c5e56e19571

Comment: I think you're making this too difficult.  I just checked on [sendgrid.com](https://sendgrid.com/) and 1.2M emails per month is not even their highest tier.  It isn't cheap - about USD $650/month but you don't have to build the exact thing that already exists somewhere else.  They have tools to let you customize and handle spam/unsubscribe/open counts and a bunch more.  I have no financial interest in them (and there are other providers) but have used them successfully in the past.

Comment: @Austin I'd be willing to bet good money you can do it with a third party. I've used Mailgun and they have an API for sending emails and support for webhooks. I seriously doubt it couldn't be done with Sendgrid or Mailgun.

Comment: I don't doubt that it couldn't be done but there are some other business requirements that require it to be built in house.

Comment: Why is SNS OK then if Mailgun or Sendgrid aren't?

Comment: How is SES not a third party email service, but Sendgrid is?

Comment: SES doesn't exist inside your VPC. It is an external service.

Answer (score 6):

On the surface Lambda might appear to be a good solution, but it is not.

You will either need to develop your own software or port / migrate an existing solution. Managing email lists and sending emails is a task that will fit just fine on a normal EC2 instance (sized appropriately) along with RDS. The process of sending a single email is slow (for a lot of SMTP servers several seconds per email) so overlapping is critical. With Lambda you will pay for all those seconds that Lambda waits for the SMTP server to accept each email.

There are a lot of issues in sending bulk (large quantity of) emails. This is why third party services are becoming so popular. They provide a managed service that you just plug into your app and move on to the next task.

If you are going to use AWS to send emails, consider reading this Best Practices document:

[Amazon Simple Email Service Email Sending Best Practices](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-amazon-ses-best-practices.pdf)

Comment: We currently are sending them ~20 per second with our old implementation in place.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind when implementing a Lambda-based solution is that each lambda is guaranteed to run ***at least once***. Occasionally there will be a glitch and some of your users will receive duplicate emails. [Here](https://blog.sungardas.com/CTOLabs/2017/06/run-lambda-run/) it is estimated that around 0.02% of all invocations result in multiple executions.